# Equivalence of definitions for locally compact

Tags: general-topology

Show that, for a Hausdorff space $X$, if each point $x\in X$ has an open neighborhood $U$ such that $\overline{U}$ is compact, then for each $x\in X$ and every open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $X$, there is an open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $\overline{V}\subseteq U$ and $\overline{V}$ is compact.

My attempt: Assume $X$ is Hausdorff. First, assume that each point $x\in X$ has an open neighborhood $U$ such that $\overline{U}$ is compact. Let $V$ be another arbitrary open neighborhood of $x$. Then, considering $\overline{U}$ a subspace of $X$ which is compact and Hausdorff,  $V\cap\overline{U}$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ in $\overline{U}$. Take another open neighborhood of $x$, $W$, and consider $W\cap (V\cap\overline{U})$, which is open in $\overline{U}$ and contains $x$. $\overline{W\cap (V\cap\overline{U})}$ is compact since it is the closed subset of a compact space. Then we have $W\cap (V\cap\overline{U})$ an open neighborhood of $x$ whose closure is compact, and $\overline{W\cap (V\cap\overline{U})}\subseteq U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let $x \in X$ and let $U$ be an open neighbourhood of $x$. By assumption $x$ also has an open neighbourhood $U_x$ such that $\overline{U_x}$ is compact.

Now consider the subspace $K=\overline{U_x}$ of $X$, which is compact and Hausdorff (as $X$ is, so are all its subspaces) and by definition of the subspace topology $U \cap K$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$, and so by regularity of $K$ (which follows from compact plus Hausdorff) we have some relatively open $W'$ of $K$ that contains $x$ and such that $\overline{W'} \subseteq U \cap K$ (closure taken in $K$). And $W'=W \cap K$ for some open $W$ in $X$, of course. Now take $V=U \cap W \cap U_x$, an open neighbourhood of $x$ and note that $\overline{V}\subseteq U$, as required.

Comment: Can I rewrite it like this? (check edits) Does it make sense?

Comment: @mrose Yes, that looks like a better attempt now. The crux is to realise that you can work to refine in a compact Hausdorff subspace which is normal even.